# Using Javascript to hide an element or specific id in html

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I wanna write a javascript function that hides an element/specfic id in my html code once the user clicks on that text. What I have right now isn't hiding the html. I'm not so good at javascript so I appreciate any help

what i have for my html:

```
<head> <script type="text/javascript" src="hide.js"></script> </head>

<h1 onclick = "hide(this)">[Name]</h1>
```

What I have for my javascript function:

```
function hide (el) {
    el.style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

Comment: You're not passing `el` to the function. `onclick="hide(this)"` supposed to do the trick.

Comment: Now what? You've edited the question according to comment/answer, or fixed it to correspond the real code you have?

Comment: no sorry I edited before you posted your comment, that was my bad, but its still not working. I realized that mistake before I checked the comments/answer to this question

Comment: Your code [seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/pw5e5b4q/) ...? Is there something we are not seeing? (The confusion with the edit might be caused by my worm-degree connection ;)

Comment: ok thanks! ill look into it more, now that I at least see that the function does work. Must be that where I have my javascript file is not properly linked to my html file?

Comment: Is the path of javascipt file correct?

Answer (score 1):

You must pass `this` to the javascript function as parameter:

```
<h1 onclick = "hide(this)">[Name]</h1>
```

`this` represents the HTML DOM element.

```js
function hide(el) {
  el.style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

```html
<h1 onclick="hide(this)">[Name]</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change you function:

```
hide = function(el) {
   el.style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

You can test here:  http://jsfiddle.net/wzte1ru9/5/

Comment: Change the function to what? The version you've in the answer is an exact copy of the function in the OP. Assigning the function to a variable doesn't change anything. Notice, that the fiddle I've linked in my comment is using function declaration, and it works fine.

Comment: You need write the function like a variable assignation. The original example dont work: http://jsfiddle.net/9g7v3urn/

Comment: You've "`onDomready`" set in the fiddle. OP has the script in `head`, which corresponds to "`No wrap-in <head>`" at jsFiddle. You might want to read [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname).